# What is this colorful coil under the hood?

Tags: part-identification, hood

I took a look under the hood of my friend’s car and saw this colorful coil:

[image: Colorful coil]

What is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the exhaust. Most likely it's part of the exhaust gas recirculation (EGR) system. The part you are pointing out is a part which allows a bit of flex without any damage coming to the tube as a whole.

Comment: Why does it have this color?

Comment: Because it's been heated and the type of metal it's made out of, I'd assume? I'd bet the metal is a bit softer than the regular exhaust pipes to allow it to flex better. This may have caused the color. It's definitely nothing to worry about.

Comment: It is stainless steel . the color is heat tint caused by different thicknesses of oxides. Just like a motorcycle stainless exhaust.  Least thickness ( lower temperature ) gold . then pink, then pinkish blue, then blue , then purple ( thickest = hot). Then it will turn black if the oxide is thick enough. Steel goes through the same color range at much lower temperatures.